# How can we stop reloading the angular page if api throws an error and instead display that error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I have a problem in my angular app that if any api throws any error then the app reloads automatically once instead of displaying that error.So please help me to stop the reload of app and only display that error

I have tried the fllowing below code but it could not work , it again throws error

```
 onSubmit() {
          var  data = {
            encrypted_key : this.userId
            }
        this.userService.signup(data)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.data=data
                },
                error => {
                  this.displayerror = error;

                });
    } 
This is .ts file
```

```
<button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit<button>
 HTML file
<p>{{displayerror}}</p>
```

Expected result :

Display the error only

Actula result :
It will reload the entire page and again displays the button

Comment: are you using any HTTP interceptor in your project? best way to handle API errors inside the HTTP interceptor. can you show me where you're written the code for reloading the page when error occurs in api?

Comment: Hi Prince
```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { User } from '@app/_models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll(user:any) {
        return this.http.post<User[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/auth/users`, user);
    }

```

Comment: Hi, did you happen to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an error in onSubmit then it will get refreshed.so make sure you have imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule ** from **@angular/forms in your respective module.ts or in app.module.ts

Also check example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yghuby

Also you can use ngForm derictive

```
<form  #createForm="ngForm" class="login-form text-center" (ngSubmit)="Update()" (keydown.enter)
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
 import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HeroFormComponent } from './hero-form/hero-form.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroFormComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hii Anton
I have already imported the reactive and forms module

Comment: Also you can use ngForm derictive

Comment: Hi anton ,
Thanks for your quick response
but this is not form , it comes for every function not only in form
is there any other way to stop reload & display only error

Comment: Ok. It is not clear. If you can show me your code on stackblitz - that I can play with your code.

Comment: nginit(){
onSubmit()
}
onSubmit() {
          var  data = {
            encrypted_key : this.userId
            }
        this.userService.signup(data)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.data=data
                },
                error => {
                  this.displayerror = error;

                });
    } 
This is .ts file

Answer (score 0):

In html pass $event object so that you can stop it inside handle.

```
<button (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">Submit<button>
 HTML file
<p>{{displayerror}}</p>
```

inside your onSubmit function just prevent it.

```
onSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
}
```

use (ngSubmit) instead of (click)

Comment: Hi aditiya thanks for the suggestion.
but actully the function is called in initial
nginit(){
this.onsSubmit()
}

Comment: @Sudhin can you make type=button in html markup ,it might be taking type = submit by default that causing page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can `return false` when you getting an error from APIs

```
onSubmit() {
      var  data = {
        encrypted_key : this.userId
        }
    this.userService.signup(data)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.data=data
            },
            error => {
              this.displayerror = error;
              return false;
            });
}
```

Comment: Hi Pramod ,
Thanks for the suggesstion
but i have tried this its not working

Comment: @Sudhin

If there is an error in onSubmit then it will get refreshed.so make sure you have imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule ** from **@angular/forms in your respective module.ts or in app.module.ts

Comment: Hi pramod,
i Have added those also in app.module.ts file